# Why is $L^{\infty}$ not separable?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces, separable-spaces

$l^p (1≤p<{\infty})$ and $L^p (1≤p<∞)$ are separable spaces.

> What on earth has changed when the value of $p$ turns from a finite number to ${\infty}$?

Our teacher gave us some hints that there exists an uncountable subset such that the distance of any two elements in it is no less than some $\delta>0$.

Actually I don't understand the question very well, but I hope I have made the question clear enough.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you say that you don't understand the question very well, which part is unclear? Do you know what it means for a metric space to be separable, or inseparable? Do you know the definition of the $\ell^\infty$-norm?

Comment: @Andylang: if you think Yemon Choi's comment is good, how about answering some of the clarifying questions he asked?

Comment: @ Henning Makholm :Yes,I know the definition of inseparable space.And the norm of $l^p$ (p is finite) is clear for me.I will google the norm of $l^{\infty}$.Thanks.

Comment: Here's a thread containing the answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33044/prove-that-ell-infty-and-mathcall-infty-are-non-separable-normed (I earlier voted to close as a duplicate but given that the closed question is closed too, I'm a bit unsure if closure is a good idea).

Comment: For $\ell^{\infty}$, you can see here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170068/which-of-the-following-metric-spaces-are-separable/

Answer (score 91, accepted):

To be separable means to have a countable dense subset.  Suppose that $(M, d)$ is a metric space and that  $U\subseteq M$ be an uncountable subset and $r > 0$. Suppose that for all $x \neq  y \in U$, $d(x,y) \ge r$.  Let $C$ be any countable subset of $M$.  Then $C$ can only meet a countable number of the balls $B_{r/2}(x)$ for $x\in U$.  Let $G$ be the union of all $B_{r/2}(x)$ for $x\in U$ that do not meet $C$.  $G$ is a nonempty open subset of $M$ that does not meet $C$.

There can be no countable dense subset of $M$.

Consider the case of $\ell^\infty$.  For each subset $Q$ of the integers, let $x_Q$ be the sequence that is 1 on $G$ and 0 off of it.  The $x_Q$ are uncountable and any two elements of this collection are distance 1 apart.  We have just shown that $\ell^\infty$ is not separable.

You can generate a similar construct for $L^\infty$.  Consider the uncountable subclass of characteristic functions $\{\chi_{B_r(0)}\}_{r>0}\subseteq L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Then each pair of distinct elements in it would be 1 unit distance apart. *Ergo* there cannot be any countable subset of $L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ that is dense in it.

Comment: (+1) Why do we have to let $G$ be the union of all $B_{r/2}(x)$ that do not meet $C$? Isn't choosing one such $B_{r/2}(x)$ that does not meet $C$ suffice to show that $C$ is not dense? (using this definition: A is dense in X if for any point x in X, any neighborhood of x contains at least one point from A)

Comment: Thank you ncmathsadist and I would like to see an answer to the comment of  @yoyostein, thanks again

Answer (score 6):

With the topology $\|f-g\|_{l^\infty}=\sup_i |f_i-g_i|$ it is easy to show if C is any countable set, and $(f_{ij})_j$ a sequence of elements of $C$, you can take an element $h\in l^\infty$ so that
$h_i= 0$ if $|f_{ii}|>1$, $h_i=2$ otherwise, hence $\|f_{j}-h\|>1/2$ for all $j$. Then no ball of radius $1/2$ around $h$ can contain an element of $C$.

Comment: I think it should be $\|f_j-h\|\geq\|f_{jj}-h_j\|\geq1$ (which, of course, doesn't change the result).

Comment: Also "no ball" is a bit misleading since there is just one ball of radius 1/2 around $h$. May "no ball of radius smaller 1" would fit here better.

Comment: Why do you say topology? Isn't that just the norm?

Comment: The norm induces the topology.