# There does not exist $f\in (l^\infty)^*$ with $\ker f = c_0$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

There does not exist $f\in (l^\infty)^*$ with $\ker f = c_0$.

$c_0$ is the closed subspace of $l^\infty$ with the property that if $x = (x_1, x_2,...) \in c_0$ then
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }x_n = 0.$$

**My attempt:**
Now suppose $f\in (l^\infty)^*$ and $\ker f = c_0$. For each $x\in c_0$, we have
$$f(x) = 0.$$
Since the dual space of $c_0$ is $l^1$, we can identify $f\big|_{c_0}$ with the $0$ element in $l^1$.

Also I know that the natural map from $l^1$ to $(l^1)^{**} = (l^\infty)^*$ is isometric, can we conclude that $f$ has to be the zero functional in $(l^\infty)^*$? So that the $\ker f$ has to be the entire space.

Thank you very much!

Comment: But there are nonzero continuous linear forms on $l^\infty$ that vanish on $c_0$. Try with the codimension of $\ker f$.

Comment: @DanielFischer could you point me to some reference for codimension in infinite dimensional normed vector spaces. I have only studied it in the setting of linear algebra and abstract algebra. Thank you very much!

Comment: @DanielFischer There is a nonzero continuous linear form on $\ell^{\infty}$ that vanish on $c_0$.

Comment: @Hamou That's what I wrote (except I used the plural). Are you asking for an example, or did you think I wrote the opposite?

Comment: @Xiao I can't point to a specific reference, but if $F\subset E$ is a linear subspace, the codimension of $F$ in $E$ is $\operatorname{codim}_E F = \dim (E/F)$. Since every linear map $T \colon E \to G$ with $F\subset \ker T$ induces an injective map $\hat{T} \colon (E/F) \to G$, what can you say about the codimension of $\ker f$ if $f$ is a linear functional?

Comment: why $\hat{T} $ is injective? if $F=0$. did you mean surjective

Comment: @Hamou Oops, I thought of $F = \ker T$, not $F\subset \ker T$. Thanks for the correction. (But it would be good to `@`-ping in such cases, if I hadn't happened by again, I wouldn't have noticed the mistake.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume such functional exists. Kernel of any functional is ofcodimension $1$, hence $\ell_\infty=c_0\oplus\mathbb{C}$. Note that $c_0$ is separable, so does $c_0\oplus\mathbb{C}$. Thus $\ell_\infty$ is separable. [Contradiction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/660418/why-is-l-infty-not-separable), because $\ell_\infty$ is not separable.