# Follow up to an answer: Why is $l^{\infty}$ not separable?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, separable-spaces

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/660418/why-is-l-infty-not-separable) question thread, user940 answered and said that, "Assume that $A⊂l^∞$ is countable..."

I want to understand:

1. why can we assume something like this? can assuming something like this make our result less general?
2. can we do a similar proof without assuming that $A$ is countable, and instead by considering *any* sequence $a_k \in A$ such that $||a_k-b||>$ some $\epsilon?$

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to assume that? If the assumption leads to something useful or not is a different matter.

Comment: A space is separable if it has a countable dense subset. That user is proving that for each countable subset $A$ of $\ell^\infty$, $A$ is not dense in $\ell^\infty$. That is, they are proving exactly the negation of the statement "$\ell^\infty$ is separable".

Comment: @RhysSteele thank you!